# Need print logo without any ID & class

Tags: functions, templates, logo

In `functions.php`:

```
function mymy_setup() {
    // Add theme support for Custom Logo.
    add_theme_support( 'custom-logo', array(
        'width'       => 80,
        'height'      => 40,
        'flex-width'  => true,
    ) );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mymy_setup' );
```

In template:

```
<?php the_custom_logo(); ?>
```

The HTML output:

```
<a href="http://localhost/myweb/" class="custom-logo-link" rel="home" itemprop="url"><img width="80" height="40" src="http://localhost/myweb/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/cropped-cropped-1-2.jpg" class="custom-logo" alt="" itemprop="logo" /></a>
```

What I need is:

```
<a href="http://localhost/myweb/"><img src="http://localhost/myweb/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/cropped-cropped-1-2.jpg" /></a>
```

How to print without any ID & class? (I also can accept print logo URL only)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using the [**`get_custom_logo`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_custom_logo/) filter.

```
add_filter( 'get_custom_logo', 'wpse250683_custom_logo_output' );

function wpse250683_custom_logo_output() {
    $custom_logo_id = get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' );
    $attachment     = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $custom_logo_id, 'full', false );
    $attachment_url = '';
    if ( is_array( $attachment ) )
        $attachment_url = $attachment[0];
    $html = sprintf( '<a href="%1$s"><img src="%2$s" /></a>',
        esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ),
        $attachment_url
    );
    return $html;
}
```